# How can I get nginx NOT to serve index.html?

Tags: nginx

I have a location configured to look like this

```
location /api/files {
    autoindex on;
    autoindex_exact_size on;        
    autoindex_format json;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    alias /srv/files/;
}
```

I'd like it to NEVER serve index.html, always the JSON file listing. The index should be served from a different location.

How can I do that?

Comment: @RichardSmith Answers should be posted below as answers, rather than in temporary comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`autoindex` works in conjunction with `index`. As you have noticed, if `index` finds a match, that will be used in preference to displaying the contents of the directory.

Unfortunately, `index` does not have an off switch, but you can effectively disable it by using an unlikely filename as the parameter.

Simply override the `index` directive within the `location` block.

For example:

```
location /api/files {
    index nonextistent;
    autoindex on;
    autoindex_format json;
    ...
}
```